# underline word in vim without changing its color

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I'd like use underlined text for some syntactic groups in vim. A simple example would the Search group:

```
:highlight Search guibg=black guifg=yellow gui=underline
```

However, when I do that, all search matches also change their colors to white. Can I underline them all, but preserve their original colors?

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead:

```
:highlight Search guibg=none guifg=none gui=underline
```

That should preserve the match's foreground and background colors. The underline color will match the foreground color.